# cifar100: spikes in accuracy and loss

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torch, resnet

I am training a `preactresnet18` network on the cifar100 dataset. I have adjusted all training settings but still, I can see spikes in my training loss and accuracy. I have no idea why it's happening. I have changed the learning rate batch size but still i cannot solve it.

**Code**

```
parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=200, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='number of total epochs to run (default: 200)')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=256, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='mini-batch size (default: 256), this is the total '
                         'batch size of all GPUs on the current node when '
                         'using Data Parallel')
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning-rate', default=0.0001, type=float,
                    metavar='LR', help='initial learning rate (defualt: 0.1)',
                    dest='lr')
parser.add_argument('--momentum', default=0.9, type=float, metavar='M',
                    help='momentum (default: 0.9)')
parser.add_argument('--wd', '--weight-decay', default=5e-4, type=float,
                    metavar='W', help='weight decay (default: 5e-4)',
                    dest='weight_decay')
```

**Loader**

```
def cifar100_loader(batch_size, num_workers, datapath, cuda):
normalize = transforms.Normalize(
    mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465],
    std=[0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010])
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    normalize,
])
transform_val = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    normalize,
])

trainset = CIFAR100(
    root=datapath, train=True, download=True,
    transform=transform_train)
valset = CIFAR100(
    root=datapath, train=False, download=True,
    transform=transform_val)

if cuda:
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        trainset,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        valset,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)
else:
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        trainset,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=False)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        valset,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=False)

return train_loader, val_loader
```

**Main**

```
    import time
import pathlib
from os.path import isfile

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn

import models
from colorBox import Rand_Square_Mask
from utils import *
from config import config
from data import DataLoader
import wandb

# for ignore imagenet PIL EXIF UserWarning
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "(Possibly )?corrupt EXIF data", UserWarning)

best_acc1 = 0

wandb.init(project="ICCV2023", entity="text")


def main():
    global opt, start_epoch, best_acc1
    opt = config()

    if opt.cuda and not torch.cuda.is_available():
        raise Exception('No GPU found, please run without --cuda')

    print('\n=> creating model \'{}\''.format(opt.arch))

    if opt.arch == 'preactresnet18':
        model = models.preactresnet18()
    else:
        model = models.__dict__[opt.arch](opt.dataset, opt.width_mult)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=opt.lr,
                          momentum=opt.momentum, weight_decay=opt.weight_decay,
                          nesterov=True)
    start_epoch = 0
    n_retrain = 0

    if opt.cuda:
        torch.cuda.set_device(opt.gpuids[0])
        with torch.cuda.device(opt.gpuids[0]):
            model = model.cuda()
            criterion = criterion.cuda()
        model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=opt.gpuids,
                                output_device=opt.gpuids[0])
        cudnn.benchmark = True

    # checkpoint file
    ckpt_dir = pathlib.Path('checkpoint')
    ckpt_file = ckpt_dir / opt.arch / opt.dataset / opt.ckpt

    # for resuming training
    if opt.resume:
        if isfile(ckpt_file):
            print('==> Loading Checkpoint \'{}\''.format(opt.ckpt))
            checkpoint = load_model(model, ckpt_file, opt)

            start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])

            print('==> Loaded Checkpoint \'{}\' (epoch {})'.format(
                opt.ckpt, start_epoch))
        else:
            print('==> no checkpoint found \'{}\''.format(
                opt.ckpt))
            return

    # Data loading
    print('==> Load data..')
    train_loader, val_loader = DataLoader(opt.batch_size, opt.workers,
                                          opt.dataset, opt.datapath,
                                          opt.cuda)

    # for evaluation
    if opt.evaluate:
        if isfile(ckpt_file):
            print('==> Loading Checkpoint \'{}\''.format(opt.ckpt))
            checkpoint = load_model(model, ckpt_file, opt)

            start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])

            print('==> Loaded Checkpoint \'{}\' (epoch {})'.format(
                opt.ckpt, start_epoch))

            # evaluate on validation set
            print('\n===> [ Evaluation ]')
            start_time = time.time()
            acc1, acc5 = validate(val_loader, model, criterion)
            save_eval(['{}-{}-{}'.format(opt.arch, opt.dataset, opt.ckpt[:-4]),
                       str(acc1)[7:-18], str(acc5)[7:-18]], opt)
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            print('====> {:.2f} seconds to evaluate this model\n'.format(
                elapsed_time))
            return
        else:
            print('==> no checkpoint found \'{}\''.format(
                opt.ckpt))
            return

    # train...
    train_time = 0.0
    validate_time = 0.0
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, opt.epochs):
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, opt.lr)
        print('\n==> {}/{} training'.format(opt.arch, opt.dataset))
        print('==> Epoch: {}, lr = {}'.format(
            epoch, optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]))

        # train for one epoch
        print('===> [ Training ]')
        start_time = time.time()
        acc1_train, acc5_train = train(train_loader,
                                       epoch=epoch, model=model,
                                       criterion=criterion, optimizer=optimizer)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        train_time += elapsed_time
        print('====> {:.2f} seconds to train this epoch\n'.format(
            elapsed_time))

        # evaluate on validation set
        print('===> [ Validation ]')
        start_time = time.time()
        acc1_valid, acc5_valid = validate(val_loader, model, criterion)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        validate_time += elapsed_time
        print('====> {:.2f} seconds to validate this epoch\n'.format(
            elapsed_time))

        # remember best Acc@1 and save checkpoint and summary csv file
        is_best = acc1_valid > best_acc1
        best_acc1 = max(acc1_valid, best_acc1)
        state = {'epoch': epoch + 1,
                 'model': model.state_dict(),
                 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
        summary = [epoch,
                   str(acc1_train)[7:-18], str(acc5_train)[7:-18],
                   str(acc1_valid)[7:-18], str(acc5_valid)[7:-18]]
        save_model(state, epoch, is_best, opt)
        save_summary(summary, opt)

    avg_train_time = train_time / (opt.epochs - start_epoch)
    avg_valid_time = validate_time / (opt.epochs - start_epoch)
    total_train_time = train_time + validate_time
    print('====> average training time per epoch: {:,}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(avg_train_time // 60), avg_train_time % 60))
    print('====> average validation time per epoch: {:,}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(avg_valid_time // 60), avg_valid_time % 60))
    print('====> training time: {}h {}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(train_time // 3600), int((train_time % 3600) // 60), train_time % 60))
    print('====> validation time: {}h {}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(validate_time // 3600), int((validate_time % 3600) // 60), validate_time % 60))
    print('====> total training time: {}h {}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(total_train_time // 3600), int((total_train_time % 3600) // 60), total_train_time % 60))


def train(train_loader, **kwargs):
    epoch = kwargs.get('epoch')
    model = kwargs.get('model')
    criterion = kwargs.get('criterion')
    optimizer = kwargs.get('optimizer')

    batch_time = AverageMeter('Time', ':6.3f')
    data_time = AverageMeter('Data', ':6.3f')
    losses = AverageMeter('Loss', ':.4e')
    top1 = AverageMeter('Acc@1', ':6.2f')
    top5 = AverageMeter('Acc@5', ':6.2f')
    progress = ProgressMeter(len(train_loader), batch_time, data_time,
                             losses, top1, top5, prefix="Epoch: [{}]".format(epoch))

    # switch to train mode
    model.train()

    end = time.time()
    for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # measure data loading time
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)

        if opt.cuda:
            target = target.cuda(non_blocking=True)

        # compute output
        mask1 = Rand_Square_Mask(percent_augment=0.2, img_size=(32, 32), divisions=2, rand_spawn=False)
        images = mask1(input)

        output = model(images)
        loss = criterion(output, target)

        # measure accuracy and record loss
        acc1, acc5 = accuracy(output, target, topk=(1, 5))
        losses.update(loss.item(), input.size(0))
        top1.update(acc1[0], input.size(0))
        top5.update(acc5[0], input.size(0))

        # compute gradient and do SGD step
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        wandb.log({"loss": losses.avg, "epoch": opt.epochs, 'acc': top1.avg, 'batch': opt.batch_size})

        # measure elapsed time
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)

        if i % opt.print_freq == 0:
            progress.print(i)

        end = time.time()

    print('====> Acc@1 {top1.avg:.3f} Acc@5 {top5.avg:.3f}'
          .format(top1=top1, top5=top5))

    return top1.avg, top5.avg


def validate(val_loader, model, criterion):
    batch_time = AverageMeter('Time', ':6.3f')
    losses = AverageMeter('Loss', ':.4e')
    top1 = AverageMeter('Acc@1', ':6.2f')
    top5 = AverageMeter('Acc@5', ':6.2f')
    progress = ProgressMeter(len(val_loader), batch_time, losses, top1, top5,
                             prefix='Test: ')

    # switch to evaluate mode
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        end = time.time()
        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
            if opt.cuda:
                target = target.cuda(non_blocking=True)

            # compute output
            output = model(input)
            loss = criterion(output, target)

            # measure accuracy and record loss
            acc1, acc5 = accuracy(output, target, topk=(1, 5))
            losses.update(loss.item(), input.size(0))
            top1.update(acc1[0], input.size(0))
            top5.update(acc5[0], input.size(0))

            # measure elapsed time
            batch_time.update(time.time() - end)

            if i % opt.print_freq == 0:
                progress.print(i)

            end = time.time()

        print('====> Acc@1 {top1.avg:.3f} Acc@5 {top5.avg:.3f}'
              .format(top1=top1, top5=top5))

    return top1.avg, top5.avg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('====> total time: {}h {}m {:.2f}s'.format(
        int(elapsed_time // 3600), int((elapsed_time % 3600) // 60), elapsed_time % 60))
```

**Training Configuration**

Single GPU (NVIDIA 3080 `12 GB`)
The batch size is `384`
Epochs `400`
Learning rate `0.001`, momentum 0.9 weight decay `5e-4`

Results
[image]

Comment: Have you tried tuning the learning rate? Try decreasing the learning rate or using a learning rate schedule.

Comment: I have tried a lot like 0.1, 0.01, and 0.001 Can you please give me the learning rate for cifar100?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. You could keep going 0.0001. You also can vary the learning rate on the different layers.

Comment: It looks a bit suspect, i would check your accuracy calculator to make sure it's operating over the batch correctly. The fact that the jumps are occurring pretty regularly seems to tell me that something is being set/reset at the beginning of the batch. Can you edit your question with any of this code?

Comment: Sure, I will update

Comment: @iohans i have try with 0.0001 still i see spikes